# How to modify group policy object via python ldap?

Tags: python, openldap

i am trying to link gpos to OUs. Also, i want to add new gpos and modify policy settings/preferences. i am stuck at the latter part. any ideas/tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: some code of where you got so far would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is just an update to the OU.  For instance to set a custom password policy set the attribute pwdPolicySubentry with the value of a dn that points to the custom policy on the object.  This would just be a straight forward modify operation.